# How to include 'varIdent' (nlme) in a lmer (lme4) model formula?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I am fitting the following model ("`cma`") with lme:

```
ctrl<-lmeControl(maxIter=200,msMaxIter=200, niterEM=200)
vf1<-varIdent(form=~1|Region)
cf<-formula(rrP~plotsize+altitude+baseT+baseP+baseN)
cma<-lme(cf,data=dat, random=~1|Region, weights=vf1,control=ctrl,na.action=na.exclude,method="ML")
```

I want to do "the same" in lmer. How do I account for 'weights' in lmer as it is currently in my lme formula (i.e `weights=varIdent(form=~1|Region)`)?

Comment: lme4 does not support fitting of variance structures.

Comment: Ok. Indeed that's what I was thinking, but better to ask in case someone knew any trick to do that. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It might be possible, see the hack suggested here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/214007/28666.