# How can Welch's t-test be expressed in lme4

Tags: regression, t-test, heteroscedasticity, lme4-nlme

In a previous question ([Equivalent to Welch's t-test in GLS framework](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142685/equivalent-to-welchs-t-test-in-gls-framework)) it was asked whether `nlme` 
can reproduce Welch's t-test.

Below is an abridged version of this older question:

> A standard independent samples t-test (where it is assumed that the samples being compared are drawn from populations with equal variance) can be expressed as follows:
>
> > $$Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i + \varepsilon_i$$
>
> where $Y$ is the outcome and $X$ is a binary variable corresponding to group membership. The significance test of $\beta_1$ will produce the same t statistic as the standard independent samples t-test. Thus, the two commands below produce the same statistics (with the same degrees of freedom):

```
t.test(extra~group, data = sleep, var.equal = TRUE)  
lm(extra~group, data = sleep)
```

The provided answer to this question indicated that using `gls` (in the `nlme` package) with specificed weights

```
weights=varIdent(form = ~ 1 | group))
```

would do the trick.

I am curious whether this can also be implemented in `lme4` (using `lmer`). When going through the help file of `lme4` I could not find anything that corresponds to the weight option in `nlme::gls`.

Comment: According to http://rpsychologist.com/r-guide-longitudinal-lme-lmer, "Only `lme` allows modeling heteroscedastic residual variance at level 1 [via `weights=`]".

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/267439 ("lme4 does not support fitting of variance structures").

Comment: But then, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/214007/28666 where BenBolker gives a hack to make it work in lmer!

Comment: I tried the hack and it works. I updated Jake's answer in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142685 to include this hack there. Unless he (Jake) does not like it and removes my edit, your Q will be a duplicate :-)