# What is the difference between factor-specific residual variance and factor specific random slopes

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, heteroscedasticity

Ben Bolker has posted a short discussion about "Factor-specific variances in R"  http://rpubs.com/bbolker/6298. My question extends from this discussion: what is the difference between allowing for heteroscedasticity in the residual errors and allowing for factor specific variances as random slopes in the random effects term? Can I claim to deal with heteroscedasticity between factors using random slopes?

It is clear that allowing for factor-specific slopes affects the standard errors of the estimates (see summary figure below). So, what is the difference between removing residual variation from `sigma` to the random effects-term or the variance function (available in `lme`)?

#### Example data/code:

Using the same data as in Ben's post:

```
library(ggplot2); library(dplyr); library(nlme); library(lme4); library(afex)

set.seed(101)
dsd <- c(1,2,3)
nblock <- 25
ntot <- 750
nfac <- 3
d <-expand.grid(f=letters[1:nfac],g=1:nblock,rep=seq(ntot/(nblock*nfac)))
d$fg <- with(d,interaction(g,f))
delta <- 4:6
u <- rnorm(nblock*nfac,mean=0,sd=rep(dsd,each=nblock))
d$y <- rnorm(nrow(d),mean=delta[d$f],sd=0.2)+u[d$fg]
```

This creates a data set with factor `f`, grouping `g`, replicate `rep` and dependent variable `y`.

```
head(d)
  f g rep  fg
1 a 1   1 1.a
2 b 1   1 1.b
3 c 1   1 1.c
4 a 2   1 2.a
5 b 2   1 2.b
6 c 2   1 2.c
```

nlme model assuming homoscedasticity

`m1 <- lme(y ~ f-1, random = ~1|g, data = d)`

nlme model with heteroscedastic errors using `weights` and `varIdent`

`m2 <- lme(y ~ f-1, random = ~1|g, weights = varIdent(form = ~1|f), data = d)`

Comparing these two models suggests that `m2` has a better fit.

`AIC(m1, m2)`

```
    df      AIC
 m1  5 2982.225
 m2  7 2316.266
```

Examining the parameter estimates for the variance function in `m2` factor level `b` and `c` have ~11 and ~16 times bigger residual variance than level `a`.

```
Variance function:
 Structure: Different standard deviations per stratum
 Formula: ~1 | f 
 Parameter estimates:
       a        b        c 
 1.00000 10.87984 15.93487
```

Instead of estimating the variance function to estimate factor specific residual variance I allow for different slopes in the random effects term.

`m3 <- lme(y ~ f-1, random = list(g = pdDiag(~1 + f)), data = d)`

This results in StdDev of the `c` ~3.5 times that of the `intercept` level (`a`).

```
Random effects:
  Formula: ~1 + f | g
  Structure: Diagonal
         (Intercept)      fb       fc  Residual
 StdDev:   0.8483291 2.04441 2.989323 0.1898166
```

Doing the same in with `lmer` gives similar results, however the estimates are affected as shown in the figure below.

`m4 <- lmer(y ~ f-1 + (f|g) , data = d)`

Removning correlation between random effects using `afex::lmer_alt`

`m5 <- lmer_alt(y ~ f-1 + (1+f||g), data = d)`

Setting correlations to zero as suggested in http://rpubs.com/bbolker/6298:

```
diagLmer <- function(formula,data,
                 control=lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE="ignore")) {
  lmod <- lFormula(formula,data,control=control)
  devfun <- do.call(mkLmerDevfun, lmod)
  lower <- environment(devfun)$lower
  n <- length(lower)
  n0 <- (-1 + sqrt(1+8*n))/2  ## number of diagonal elements
  devfunw <- function(theta) {
    th <- numeric(n)
    diag_el <- which(lower==0)
    th[diag_el] <- theta
    devfun(th)
  }
  opt <- Nelder_Mead(devfunw,par=rep(1,n0),
                     lower=rep(0,n0))
  mkMerMod(environment(devfun), opt, lmod$reTrms, fr = lmod$fr)
}
```

`m6 <- diagLmer(y ~ f-1 + (f|g), data = d)`

Edit

Looking at the suggestion in [How can I test for differences in variation between groups in a mixed model (lme4)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213591/how-can-i-test-for-differences-in-variation-between-groups-in-a-mixed-model-lme/214007#214007), a last model is estimated givining random slopes per observation:

```
d <- transform(d, obs=factor(1:nrow(d)))
m7 <- lmer(y ~ f-1 + (1|g) + (f-1|obs), data = d, 
       control=lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE  = "ignore",
                           check.nobs.vs.nlev = "ignore"))
```

The results from model estimates (plotting code omitted):

[image: Estimates +- standard errors from m1 to m7]

It is clear that allowing for factor-specific slopes affects the standard errors of the estimates. So, what is the difference between removing residual variance from `sigma` to the random effects term or the variance function?