# Test-Retest reliability for mixed models

Tags: r, mixed-model, reliability, intraclass-correlation

We have an experimental setup as follows:

A set of subjects each repeat a single task multiple times in a single session, yielding a set of measurements. The same subjects then repeat the same task multiple times in a second session a week later. They are unaware of the results each time and there is unlikely to be any learning effect contributing to the results.

We have previously analysed the results from a single session, accounting for the within-subject repetition, by fitting linear mixed models with differing fixed effects and comparing them using likelihood ratio tests (as described in the excellent answers [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171187/comparing-the-within-subject-variance-between-two-groups-of-subjects)). We now wish to investigate the reliability of the results. [Side-note]

The best reference I have found for this is [1], which gives a good description and is supported by the [CorrMixed](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CorrMixed/CorrMixed.pdf) R package. They investigate reliability in terms of the measurement time, whilst treating the session (or 'cycle' in their terms) as a fixed effect. We are less interested in the measurement time (for repeated measurements within a session) and more interested in the reliability between sessions.

**What is the correct measure for reliability in our case?** (ideally with reference to the nlme or CorrMixed R packages)

[1]: Estimating the reliability of repeatedly
measured endpoints based on linear
mixed-effects models. A tutorial, Wim Van der Elst, Geert Molenberghs, Ralf-Dieter Hilgers, Geert Verbeke, and Nicole Heussen, https://www.ideal.rwth-aachen.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/10.1002_pst.1787.pdf

[Side-note]: This has been referred to as the 'Intra-Rater Reliability' in the trial notes; however I believe this is a confusing title, as variability in the measurements comes from the subjects themseves, rather than anyone rating them. To me 'Test-Retest Reliability' seems a more accurate title for what we wish to measure. Intra-Rater Reliability in the literature often seems to be considered as a subset of Test-Retest Reliability, but I would be interested in which is the correct term for what we are looking at (or whether it just comes down to semantics?).

**Example:**
Session 1 Measurements
Subject A: 2, 3, 2
Subject B: -1, -1, -2
Subject C: 4, -2, 2
Subject D: 4, 4, 5

Session 2 Measurements
Subject A: 4, 3, 3
Subject B: -1, -3, -1
Subject C: 0, -1, 3
Subject D: 3, 3, 3

Comment: I think "test-retest" is a poor choice here. It refers to the reliability of measurement, rather than of statistical analysis.  (And welcome to Cross Validated).

Comment: It is reliability of measurement that we are interested in, perhaps my question was not clear enough on that?

Comment: If it is reliability of measurement that you are concerned with, then none of the material on multilevel models is needed. I'm confused.

Comment: 'repeat a single task multiple times'. Is that just random repetition? That is, is there any systematic difference between time1 and time2 or not? Are "times" a fixed factor or are they just attempts?

Comment: Repetition is multiple attempts at the same task, therefore (within-subject) attempts are treated as a random effect in our mixed model. This is why we have been using a mixed model - is this still necessary to look at reliability?