# what "rejecting a null hypothesis" actually means?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova

I have a sample dateset consists two variables as "Score"(independent continuous) consists score of students in maths and school(dependent categorical)having 3 categories as "S1","S2","S3". I'd perform ANOVA test so null hypothesis would be that means of all samples are equal(as I've studied). The means in above mentioned samples comes as:

S1=80.5; S2=28.5; S3=60.2.

As, means for all samples are not equal so null hypothesis got rejected. Now, my question is:-

a) what does it mean by rejecting null hypothesis? what would be the conclusion?

b) Does rejecting a null hypothesis also decides that the independent variable is not a important feature for modelling and need to be removed?

Comment: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163957/what-follows-if-we-fail-to-reject-the-null-hypothesis/164094#164094

Comment: @fcop points to an exact duplicate of question (a); visit that thread for the answers.  Question (b) may be slightly different, though, because it is tantamount to asking about the role of using null hypothesis tests (that is, p-values) in model building.

Comment: @fcop do we need to perform the statistics test in between predictors or tests in between dependent variable(target) and independents variables is sufficient?